# Mapping between EC2 volume and your mounted filesystem

Tags: partition, fdisk, amazon-ec2, volume

I am running out of space on a particular filesystem. I know this with the following command `df -H`

```
$ sudo df -H
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                     4.1G   13k  4.1G   1% /dev
tmpfs                    807M   73M  734M  10% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1           106G   34G   68G  33% /
none                     4.1k     0  4.1k   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                     5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
none                     4.1G     0  4.1G   0% /run/shm
none                     105M     0  105M   0% /run/user
/dev/mapper/vg1-log      106G   97G  3.3G  97% /mnt/logs
/dev/mapper/vg1-data     732G  615G   81G  89% /mnt/data
/dev/mapper/vg1-backups  317G  317G     0 100% /mnt/backups
```

My EC2 has the following

```
Root device
/dev/sda1 - EBS ID vol-0fe5#########3b0
Block devices
/dev/sda1
/dev/sdb - EBS ID vol-0631########7560
```

How do I map which volume I should increase the size of ?

I ran the following commands to get any kind of mapping between the `EBS ID` and the `/dev/device` but did not find any

```
$ ls -l /dev/mapper
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 May 28 14:17 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jun  9 18:09 vg1-backups -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jun  9 18:09 vg1-data -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jun  9 18:09 vg1-log -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jun  9 18:09 vg1-swap -> ../dm-3
```

Please share a simple process for me to map them. But I have tried more commands
`sudo dmsetup ls --tree`, `sudo df -H`,

```
$ sudo lsblk -o KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL
KNAME     TYPE   SIZE MODEL
nvme0n1   disk   100G Amazon Elastic Block Store
nvme0n1p1 part   100G
nvme1n1   disk   1.2T Amazon Elastic Block Store
dm-0      lvm    100G
dm-1      lvm    300G
dm-2      lvm    692G
dm-3      lvm      8G
```

All point to `nvme0n1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in this [link](https://medium.com/@ripon.banik/how-to-find-ebs-volume-id-for-nvme-volume-1148d7499dc)

I was unable to install (ubuntu 18, production box) so I downloaded the sources and built it from [here](https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli). I ran the following commands

```
make
sudo make install
```

For my specific issue I ran this command

```
sudo nvme id-ctrl -v /dev/nvme1n1 > nvme1n1Log
```

The result was

```
NVME Identify Controller:
vid       : 0x1d0f
ssvid     : 0x1d0f
sn        : vol063$$$$$$$$$$60
mn        : Amazon Elastic Block Store
```

The `sn` above gives the exact volume id for the `dev`

**EDIT**

```
sudo lsblk 
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
nvme0n1              259:0    0   100G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1          259:1    0   100G  0 part / 
nvme1n1              259:2    0   1.2T  0 disk 
├─vg1-log (dm-0)     252:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /mnt/logs 
├─vg1-backups (dm-1) 252:1    0   300G  0 lvm  /mnt/backups 
├─vg1-data (dm-2)    252:2    0   692G  0 lvm  /mnt/data 
└─vg1-swap (dm-3)    252:3    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to figure out which "physical" disk is the one holding your LVM array.

If you run

```
pvs
```

this should let you know which physical disk is being used for LVM.

After that you need to extending the volume group and the logical volume. For example:

```
lvextend -l +10G /dev/mapper/you_volume
```

Comment: `pvs` does not help, returns `sudo pvs
  PV           VG   Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/nvme1n1 vg1  lvm2 a--  1.07t    0`

Comment: Thankyou for your prompt response, this is a tough problem since there is no easy way to find out. Your answer helped me realise that nothing installed on the system was going to help.